# Month-end dates for an entire year

Tags: matlab, date, datetime

I have one month-end date in serial form, `735872` (equals 2014/09/30), but I need a column vector comprising all month-end dates for the year 2014.

What's the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
datestr(datenum(2014, 1:12, eomday(2014, 1:12)))
```

Result:

```
31-Jan-2014
28-Feb-2014
31-Mar-2014
30-Apr-2014
31-May-2014
30-Jun-2014
31-Jul-2014
31-Aug-2014
30-Sep-2014
31-Oct-2014
30-Nov-2014
31-Dec-2014
```